# Is ConcurrentHashMap a reliable choice to use inside Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, hashmap

I need to map objects inside Servlet. Is ConcurrentHashMap a reliable choice to use? Will all requests get requested object from map or will there be failures?

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private Map<String, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // use map
        map.get("myObjectName");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of a `ConcurrentHashMap` is to allow **retrieval without locking**. It is suitable for multi-threaded programs that have lot of reads and very few writes.

You wrote

> Objects are not modifided after servlet init. – newbie

If by that you mean that the map does not change after servlet initialization, then you don't need a `ConcurrentHashMap` at all. You can use plain old `HashMap`. Even better would be to convert it to a non-modifiable map by using `Collections.unmodifiableMap`.

Answer (score 4):

Since the map is only initialized at startup, you should consider using Guava's [`ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html):

```
private static final ImmutableMap<String, Object> MY_MAP = ImmutableMap
       .<String, Object>builder()
       .put("asdf", myObj1)
       .put("qwerty", myObj2)
       .build();
```

The `Builder` is used to pre-populate the map with the desired values, after which calling `build()` returns the map. From then on it is immutable, making it thread safe.

You can also use the [`of`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#of%28K,%20V,%20K,%20V%29) factory methods for a limited number of key-value pairs:

```
private static final ImmutableMap<String, Object> MY_MAP = ImmutableMap.of(
        "asdf", myObj1,
        "qwerty", myObj2
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether the rest of the method alters the map or not.

There's no guarantee that changes to the map will be ACID as written.

It's usually a bad idea to have shared state like this in a servlet.  They're for handling HTTP requests.  Better to move that functionality off to a service that will do the work.

Comment: Objects are not modifided after servlet init.